# Is there a cofinality of $\mathrm{Ord}$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I was thinking about a nontrivial elem. embedding $j:V\rightarrow V$ (with a critical point), and I came across this question:

Given $cp(j)=\lambda$, is $\{\lambda,j(\lambda),j(j(\lambda))...\}$ cofinal in $\mathrm{Ord}$ (i.e. has no supremum)?

This question generalizes to whether or not $\mathrm{Ord}$ has a cofinality, and further generalizes to whether or not partially ordered proper classes have subclasses which are sets that are cofinal in them.

Comment: Since you're talking about embeddings from $V\mapsto V$, I presume you're working in a world without choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how do you define the cofinality of a class.

If you define it as a "definable class function", then of course the cofinality is going to be $\rm Ord$ itself. Any function applied to a set results a set again, so it is bounded in $\rm Ord$.

But if you allow non-definable classes, then it will depend on the model, of course. If the height of the model is some regular cardinal, then you're going to have a "regular $\rm Ord$". But it can be singular, and not even a cardinal. So in that case, it can be just so.

---

To your question, that would strongly depend on the situation and the model. There is hardly any universal answer. Since any elementary $j\colon V\to V$ is not even second-order definable.

Comment: Yes, one could add that what we can say about $j$ is very dependent on how we formalize things. For instance, the natural way to proceed is to describe the embedding in an extension of set theory to a language that has a symbol for $j$, adding axioms indicating that $j$ is elementary, and stating comprehension and replacement in the augmented language. In this setting, the critical sequence is a set, and its supremum is a (big but bounded) ordinal of cofinality $\omega$.

Comment: (Or we could work in a flavor of set theory where we can discuss proper classes, such as $\mathsf{MK}$, so $j$ is explicitly a class, and the axioms are designed so that the expected behavior takes place, so again the critical sequence $\lambda,j(\lambda),j(j(\lambda),\dots$ is bounded.)

Comment: On the other hand, one can formalize the existence of an embedding $j\!:V\to V$ in a setting where $j$ cannot appear in the replacement schema, and we now get that such a $j$ is consistent with choice, and the critical sequence is cofinal in the ordinals. This is what Paul Corazza does with his [wholeness axiom](http://cantorsattic.info/Wholeness_axiom).